# Use hyphenation command with underscores

Tags: pdftex, hyphenation, underscore

I have words in my text that contains underscores and that exceeds the boundaries of the page

[image]

the word is typed in the text as

```
FOS\_SOCIAL\_SCIENCE
```

I want the word to be able to hyphenate at the underscore boundaries.

I have tried:

```
\hyphenation{FOS-\_-NA-TU-RAL-\_-SCIEN-CE}
```

but pdfLatex return the following error

> Improper \hyphenation will be flushed. \hyphenation{FOS-_

I don't want to use the `underscore` package due to incompatibilities

I also tried

```
\renewcommand{\_}{%
    \textunderscore\nobreak\hspace{0pt}%
}
```

which doesn't work: compile without errors but the word is not hyphenated

I also tried:

```
\def\_{\_\allowbreak\hspace{0pt}}
```

which does not compile. The error message is:

> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
>   \item[FOS_NATURAL_SCIENCE]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why do you use `\nobreak` if you want something to break? Without it it works as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}

\textwidth=1mm
\begin{document}
FOS\_SOCIAL\_SCIENCE   

\renewcommand{\_}{%
    \textunderscore\nobreak\hspace{0pt}%
}

FOS\_SOCIAL\_SCIENCE

\renewcommand{\_}{%
    \textunderscore\hspace{0pt}%
}

FOS\_SOCIAL\_SCIENCE

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't wotk with without the nobreak option. I think it is unable to break in points other than the underscore, don't know why. I have `\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, draft]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` as the first lines of the preamble

Comment: It works in my example as you can see in the picture. If it doesn't work for you you will have to make a complete example.

Comment: The problem was only with `$\text{FOS\_NATURAL\_SCIENCE}$`. Removing the math environment and defining \_ as you did solved the problem